# Finite integral involving branch cut. Basic Argument Question

Tags: integration, branch-cuts

I am reading this Wikipedia article on examples of contour integrals using complex analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration). In particular, I am looking at Example (VI), which is evaluating:

$\int_0^3 \frac{x^{3/4} (3-x)^{1/4}}{5-x} dx$. The part I am confused about is when they say  $0 \leq \mathrm{arg} (3-z) \leq 2 \pi$ for $(3-z)^{1/4} = e^{\frac{\mathrm{log}(3-z)}{4}}$. How do they use that to get the numbers 0 and 2$\pi$ in the following picture? It seems to me that the picture should be flipped since the argument of $(3-z)$ is between 0 and 2$\pi$:

[image: branch cut]